# Как спрятать вывод от pip install python?

Tags: python, pip

Всем приветики омлетики, я скачиваю модули через `os.system('pip install colorama')` он выводит это :

```
Requirement already satisfied: colorama
in c:\users\ilyas\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.4.4)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
    
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

я бы хотел это спрятать, так как я паралельно вывожу в консоль загрузку, насколько я понял это будет правильно назвать тихая установка...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте флаг `--quiet`.

[Здесь можно почитать на английском](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#console-logging)

Потестил еще и с новой установкой виртуального пространства. Флаг `--quiet` не скрывает предупреждение, что установлена не последняя версия `pip`.
Чтобы полностью скрыть и это предупреждение, надо воспользоваться командой

```sh
pip install colorama --quiet --disable-pip-version-check
```

И вот тест через сам интерпретатор с `colorama`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не помогло или я не правильно написал, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: pip --no-input install colorama

Comment: @niseboy Не то написал, исправил

Comment: мне помогло, однако как же быть с error если повторно скачать модуль выводится ошибка в консоль ._.

Comment: @niseboy какая ошибка? вы сразу оба флага используете?

Comment: да, но ошибка не в pip там есть ещё сообщения когда модуль скачиваешь error, попробуйте 2 раза один модуль скачать

Comment: @niseboy может изменить подоход? И прежде чем вызывать установку сначала проверить, установлен ли данный модуль?

Comment: спасибо я так уже сделал.